# Стоит ли использовать смежные таблицы для связей?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Стоит ли использовать смежные таблицы для связей `one-to-many`, `one-to-one`?

Есть ли какая-то разница в производительности, если, например, для таблицы `products`, в которой должно быть поле `code`, я создам отдельную таблицу `products_code` и буду записывать `products_id` и `code` соответственно?

Comment: ps Я знаю для чего нужны разные виды связи, поэтому и интересуюсь, сильно ли меня закидают тапками если я буду делать как в примере.

Comment: Сильно. Если не объясните смысл данной манипуляции

Comment: разница в производительности есть конечно

Comment: @Yaroslav, можете предоставить примеры?

Comment: чем больше нормализация, тем больше тормоза

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, смысл в том, что смысла не вижу. я джуниор-разработчик, на проекте используется такая структура для некоторых таблиц.  зачем - не понимаю. вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: @Yaroslav, т.е. чем больше лишних связей, тем хуже?

Comment: @dasauser, ага, только об этом никому не говорите
а когда связи пропадают то теряется смысл БД

Comment: разбиение по таблицам имеет смысл в том случае, когда поля участвующие в условиях запроса - выносятся в main таблицу, а поля содержащие к примеру описания, поля типов text - varchar(>200) в таблицу additional
при большом количестве запросов products такая структура позволяет ускорить работу БД, в мелких БД с маленьким количеством запросов можно все данные хранить в одной таблице

Comment: @dasauser, нужно найти золотую средину

Comment: @dasauser "чем больше лишних связей, тем хуже?" В вашем вопросе целых два проблемных места. Во-первых, "связи" и "лишние связи" - это разные вещи. "лишние связи" - это очевидно плохо, а просто "связи" - это, как правило, хорошо.

Comment: Во-вторых, что значит "хуже"? Хуже проивзодительность - да, но! Реляционную модель данных придумали не для того, чтобы над разработчиками издеваться. В хорошо спроектированной БД нормализация и ограничения целостности дают возможность избежать кучи проблем ценой некоторой потери производительности. Вы можете частично отказаться от этого, но вам придется взять на себя эту работу, и не факт, что в итоге ваше решение будет быстрее, чем у нормальной реляционной СУБД.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если связь 1:1, то такой прием называют вертикальное партиционирование. Его используют для разделения структуры таблицы по-вертикали для оптимизации.

Пример 1: допустим, из таблицы `users` домашний адрес пользователя `address` читается редко. Тогда возможно разделить эту таблицу на две, и хранить адрес отдельно, читая его при необходимости. Такой прием уменьшит размер таблицы `users`, а маленькие таблицы работают быстрее.

Пример 2: в той же таблице есть поле `last_login`, обновляемое каждый раз при заходе пользователя. Но при каждом обновлении таблицы перестает работать кеш запросов! Поместив это поле в отдельную таблицу, мы сведем обновление `users` к минимуму.

Пример 3: таблица огромная. `ALTER TABLE` сделать невозможно (операция очень долгая, простой проекта). Дополнительный столбец используется редко. Есть смысл вынести это в отдельную таблицу. С другой стороны, для решения проблемы неблокирующего `ALTER TABLE` есть [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html)

Но вначале убедитесь, что эти разделенные таблицы **не** приходится объединять **постоянно**, потому как это наоборот, может уменьшить производительность.

Comment: исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: `адрес читается редко` - ну так и не читайте. Кому он мешает в таблице? Про частое обновление хочу еще добавить про особенность работы блокировок. Когда обновленная запись до коммита блокируется на чтение. Пример 3, имхо, попахивает костылестроением

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, данные на диске хранятся блоками. Читаются в память также блоками (это на уроне железа). Если часть блока будет заполнена адресом, то на ФИО, возможно, потребуется дополнительное чтение еще одного блока, так как это поле уже не умещается на границу блока. Это и лишнее чтение, и лишняя память. `попахивает костылестроением` - это не реалиционно, согласен. Но в реальности `ALTER TABLE` может занять несколько часов/дней, и в это время таблица блокируется. Умеете разрешать такие ситуации? Если да, напишите, что используете

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите чтобы было правильно и тапками не закидали, приводите все к третьей нормальной форме. Понятие четко математически определено, алгоритм тоже математически определен. "Думать не надо". 
Да простят меня, что я не привожу тут целиком определение форм и алгоритм приведения.

По вашему вопросу - следуюет отличать One-to–Zero-or-One от one-to-one.
One-to–Zero-or-One: Если у продукта может не быть code, то надо отдельную таблицу.
one-to-one: Если у каждого продукта обязательно есть code, добавляйте поле code в таблицу продуктов.

Comment: что за "третья форма"?

Comment: форма чего? структуры бд? таблицы?

Comment: Я вам очень советую прочитать про основы реляционной теории БД, раз уж вы занялись ими. Вот такая форма https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: хорошо. спасибо за совет, приму к сведению.